# Previously Able to Save and Load from PersistentDataPath on Android, Now Unable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, save, text-files, filepath

I am working on a large application interface with several mini games inside of it, using Unity 3D and C#, and this application features a sign-in page at the start of the app. The sign-in page allows the user to enter a new username, which is then saved, or to load an existing username from a drop-down list. I do not need passwords, so I have just been saving the usernames to a plain text file.

In order to save on Android, I am using the Application.persistentDataPath. Previously, this worked excellently. However, in the last weeks, this has suddenly changed. On the device, the project is able to create the file still, but is unable to load from it. The displayed usernames are blank every time. I am still able to manually check if the file exists and verify that the usernames are being saved to it.

```
    // Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt");

    Load();         //Load existing username options here (if they exist)

    Save();

    Load();

    selectedUsername.RefreshShownValue();
}

    //Saves the list of entered usernames to a text file, placed in the persistent data path (which is different per platform)
void Save()
{
    Debug.Log("Entered save function");
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt", false);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Count; i++)
    {
        w.WriteLine(menuOptions[i]);
    }

    w.Close();

}

//Reads the text file from the persistent data path, places usernames into a usable list
void Load()
{
    f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt");

    if (f.Exists && selectedUsername != null) //don't know why selectedUsername sometimes comes up as null, but that additional condition was needed
    {
        selectedUsername.ClearOptions();
        selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { "" });

        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt");
        string line;

        menuOptions.Clear();

        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            menuOptions.Add(line);
            selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { line });

        }
        selectedUsername.RefreshShownValue();
        r.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Start by debugging the code, what is happening? Add some Debug.Log-lines to check whats going on, or step thru the code.

Comment: I was able to isolate what was causing the problem, which was another plugin I was using. I believe it was causing things to be held up, or causing the loading to miss the timing. I moved the function call for the plugin and it seemed to fix it. So there are no longer any problems saving on Android and the PersistentDataPath seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to isolate what was causing the problem, which was another plugin I was using. I believe it was causing things to be held up, or causing the loading to miss the timing. I moved the function call for the plugin and it seemed to fix it. So there are no longer any problems saving on Android and the PersistentDataPath seems to work fine. If anyone else has this problem, I would check to make sure you don't have something similar going on.